# i am trying to count how many of a certain value appears in a dictionary and output it into a dictonary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

take a dictionary with a linear index and a random value assigned to each index

```
{0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 2, 8: 4, 9: 3, 10: 1}
```

my goal is to count the number of times each value occurs an out put something in the format

```
{value: number_of_appearances}
```

so the example dict would return

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 1}
```

any help would be appreciated 
{resolved}

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
a={0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 2, 8: 4, 9: 3, 10: 1}
count_dict=Counter(a.values())
print(count_dict)
#Counter({2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 1, 1: 1})
```

---

To get the count of elements that occurred 0 times use this.

```
count_dict={**{i:0 for i in range(max(a.values()))},**Counter(a.values())}
print(count_dict)
#{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#counter-objects) using the values of you dict

```
values = {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 2, 8: 4, 9: 3, 10: 1}
result = Counter(values.values())
print(result)  # Counter({4: 4, 3: 3, 2: 2, 5: 1, 1: 1})
```

If you want also the zeros keys, you may initialize with zeros, then populate with your values

```
values = {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 2, 8: 4, 9: 3, 10: 1}
result = Counter({i: 0 for i in range(max(values.values()))})
result.update(values.values())
print(result)  # Counter({4: 4, 3: 3, 2: 2, 1: 1, 5: 1, 0: 0})
print(result[2]) # 2
```